# Смена материала объекта в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь изменить материал объекта через код

```
 if (MoveToPoint(point[stage]))
    {
        stage = stage == 1 ? 0 : 1;
        if (on_x)
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, 1, 0.032f);
        else
        {
            gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0] = materials[stage];                                   
        }

    }
```

При этом материал объекта не изменяется, хотя условия выполняются. Пробовал отключать Animator и NavMeshAgent перед сменой материала ( в else), не помогло. В чём проблема? (Ниже представлен массив материалов и стандартный материал объекта)[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Необходимо обращаться к свойству material компонента MeshRenderer

```
if (MoveToPoint(point[stage]))
{
    stage = stage == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    if (on_x)
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, 1, 0.032f);
    else
        gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = materials[stage];                                   
}
```

Хорошо бы попробовать прямой вызов без условий где-то в Start()

```
gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = materials[0];
```

Comment: И так пробовал, не помогало

Comment: Возможно, проблема в вызове, либо в компоненте. Попробуйте прямой вызов (добавил в ответ) где-то в Start(). Если не получится, подкиньте, пожалуйста скриншот компонента.

Comment: Добавил скриншот компонента MeshRenderer и скрипта

Comment: Чудеса) Вы пробывали использовать прямой вызов без условий? Судя по компоненту всё должно работать.

Comment: Пробовал через Start, не сработало

Comment: Совем мистика) Попробуйте повторить мой [gameObject](https://image.prntscr.com/image/LzQSTGwRQR2KUo3nvINBBg.png) и код. `using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Material[] materials;

 void Start ()
  {
    gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = materials[0];
 }
}`

Comment: Попробовал, так работает

Comment: Ну вот, теперь по одной строчке кода добавляйте и тестируйте. Так и обнаружите проблему.

Comment: Оказалось, Animator виноват, он не давал сменить материл. Я даже теперь понял, зачем этот комментарий у себя в коде оставил: '// включение/выключение аниматора / аниматор конфликтует с чем-либо'

Answer (score 1):

Materials возвращает копию массива, а не ссылку. Надо менять массив целиком. Получаешь массив, нужный индекс заменяешь на свой. И обратно присваиваешь. Профит.

Comment: И как это сделать? Я уже всё перепробовал. Вообще никаких подвижек.

Comment: @romzes33 

**void ChangeMaterial(int id, Material myMat)
    {
        MeshRenderer mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        Material[] mats = mr.materials;
        if (id < mats.Length) mats[id] = myMat;
        mr.materials = mats;
    }**

p.s. Может медленно работать при частой смене, лучше в таком случае воспользовать MaterialPropertyBlock